# Gif image uploading from android using aws transfer utility causes crash

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using **aws-android-sdk-core-2.4.4.jar** and **aws-android-sdk-s3-2.4.4.jar** for uploading **images** and gifs to **aws server**.

```
if (BitmapUtils.checkImageUrl(path) == BitmapUtils.IMAGE_GIF) {
       ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
       metadata.setContentType("image/gif");
       File file = new File(path);
       observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, AWSUtil.getRandomName(path), new File(path), metadata);
} else
       observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, AWSUtil.getRandomName(path), new File(path));
```

`Image` uploading is working great. but when it comes to `gif`, sometimes it uploads and sometimes not. To be exact, it uploads for first time and **crashes** after that throwing error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file: 
/storage/emulated/0/Download/cartoon_birds_blue_flying_animation_clipart.gif
```

when i check my `gif` in **gallery**, it shows white or black screen only, `gif` is not loaded.

Please suggest me any ideas to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have storage access permission?

Comment: I can save if first time.. i can upload jpg all the time.

Comment: issue wasn't related to aws but file handling. so removing this question.

Comment: Have you tried uploading the gif without setting the metadata?

Comment: Did you verify all the gifs you're testing with are valid?

Comment: @donkon - if metadata is not set, then it saves only image not gif.

Comment: sorry it was a silly mistake i made, I was using images (resized and stored on cache) and later removing after upload.. but in case of gif, it wasn't necessary so the code was removing the gif after uploading for first time... Glide was showing gif in imageview because of cache.